# Breaking the SSRS report depending on the Multi Value Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on a SSRS report with a Multi Value Parameter which contains list of names. I have written an expression for the title that works like "Result for SELECTED NAME". It also have an option of (Select All) which displays all the results with title as "Result for MULTIPLE NAME". It is working fine up to this part.

Now I have to modify the report like, If i select multiple values, the report should break into pages with each selected name on different page with title for that individual parameter value(name) as "Result for SELECTED NAME".

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can place the entirety of your current report (excluding headers/footers) into a List object.  I assume youa re returning the selected values from the parameter (like Manager Name) as part of your DataSet.  Assuming this is the case

1. Create a new list
2. Insert the contents of your report into the rectangle of this List
3. Right click the List Row Header and Select Row Group -> Group Properties
4. Set the Group to Group on

   ```
   =Fields!ManagerName.Value
   ```

This approach will take a simple table like this

[image]

And break it into a list like this

[image]

Then you can just set the Tablix Properties of the List to `Add a Page Break After` to checked

Hopefully this is helpful.  If you have further questions on this then please let me know

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I worked on it and found a way to make it work. I inserted a static row and added a group with the names, then added a page break for each instance. For the title I wrote an expression by concatenation. Anyways thanks for your help. I will try that method on my next report.

Comment: If you found this helpful please mark as answer (the green tick to the left of the answer).  If you came up with your own solution please add your own answer (answering your own questions is actively encouraged!), which you can then mark as the answer later.  This is to help others who may stumble across your question in the future.

Comment: I tried you method but I am facing same problem as mine. I am adding a text box on top with the title expression that displays "Result for selected name". But when there are no records the text box is not displayed. Can you help me with  this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I worked on it and found a way to make it happen. I first created the row group for Names. Then applied the page break for each instance option. Then deleted that group column (Only deleted column but not group). Then added that group in a static column on the top, and wrote an expressions to show that group itself as a title using concatenation.

But here I faced another problem, when there is no data for the selected name, the title row isn't displayed in the preview as it also a column in the table.